# Acknowledgement POST returns empty body

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I've noticed the following behaviour from the Sandbox over the past few days. When I POST back a received IPN (to acknowledge the IPN per the PayPal IPN protocol), PayPal is responding with an empty message body instead of the body containing "VERIFIED" or "INVALID". My code was previously working fine and has not changed for quite some time. Is anyone else observing this behaviour?

Comment: It would help if you posted the code that creates the POST request -- not only because it might be relevant, but also because "why does this code get the wrong result?" is a better question for this site than "does anybody else having problems with PayPal?"